# Rendering an SSRS report in HTML 4 in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ssrs-2008

According to the list at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365156.aspx#Features it should be possible to render an SSRS report in HTML 4 when running SQL Server Express 2008 R2 with Advanced Services. However when I attempt to do so I get a ReportProcessingException.

Is it actually possible to do this or is the information in the MSDN article incorrect? I can export to the other listed formats without difficulty, but for some reason it won't work with HTML40.

Comment: Crisis averted! I had just forgotten to put a dot in between the 4 and the 0! :)

Those of us experiencing strange problems with exporting SSRS reports may want to check out the rsreportserver.config in C:\program files\microsoft sql server\MSRS10_50.SQLEXPRESS\Reporting Services\ReportServer, the <Render> section holds all the rendering extensions available to you, although some of them will not be usable depending on which version of SQL Server you are running.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365156.aspx#Features has a list of feature restrictions by eddition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crisis averted! I had just forgotten to put a dot in between the 4 and the 0! :) Those of us experiencing strange problems with exporting SSRS reports may want to check out the rsreportserver.config in C:\program files\microsoft sql server\MSRS10_50.SQLEXPRESS\Reporting Services\ReportServer, the  section holds all the rendering extensions available to you, although some of them will not be usable depending on which version of SQL Server you are running. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365156.aspx#Features has a list of feature restrictions by eddition.